# ResultSet.next() is taking too much time for few records

Tags: java, oracle, resultset, ojdbc

I'm using `OJDBC(v7)` to connect to `Oracle(11g)`, in `Java`.
In some cases on some big tables, the `Resultset` can not fetch the data in appropriate time.

For example the output records are just 2, but on the `Resultset.next()` java freezes and waits too long!

**Note1:** **The problem is not about setting `FetchSize()`, `RsultSet.TypeX` , not using connection pools like `c3p0` , ... .** **I've tested all of those.**

**Note2:** **Also when I run the query directly in `navicat`, the result is shown perfectly!**

Getting connection method:

```
public Connection getDBConnection() throws DBConnectionException {
        Connection conn = null;

        String connectionUrl;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:DBNAME");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new DBConnectionException();
        }

        return conn;
    }
```

connectiong to DB part:

```
    ...
    conn = connectionManager.getDBConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    String query = "{call ...(...)}";
    CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query,ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    stmt.setFetchSize(10000); 
    .
    .
    .
    stmt.registerOutParameter(x, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    stmt.execute();
    Resultset rs = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(x);

    while (rs.next()) {    /** Problem occurs here **/
        ...
    }
```

WHY?!

Comment: do you actually manually `commit()` the transaction once you create the SP query call?

Comment: Did you compare plans of the query when running in the client application and in JDBC ? Could be that the client application uses FIRST_ROWS(x) hint, but JDBC uses ALL_ROWS mode, and execution plans are different, and the client returns rows faster than JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

use in try catch block:

```
if ((cnn==null)||cnn.isClosed()){
    cnn=DB.getDBConnection(); //e.g. DB is instance of class where getDBConnection() resides
}
```

Then call queries. I believe somewhere in your code either you are closing connection or connection is becoming null that's why you are facing this problem.

Cheers